# Writing to flash memory fails with Optiboot

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide, flash

I am having some issue writing to flash memory on Arduino Uno.

I burned the optiboot bootloader that ships with the IDE 1.8.3 to the chip, then uploaded the [test_dospm sketch](https://github.com/Optiboot/optiboot/blob/master/optiboot/examples/test_dospm) to write content to flash memory but appears to reset the device instead.

Any idea why this might be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bootloader which ships with Arduino IDE is version 4 which was already in the Uno from factory. To use the do_spm function you need [Optiboot 8](https://github.com/Optiboot/optiboot) <s>build with this support enabled. It is not enabled in the default builds, because it doesn't fit in the usual Optiboot size for Uno</s>.

The hex file of the bootloader is [here](https://github.com/Optiboot/optiboot/blob/master/optiboot/bootloaders/optiboot/optiboot_atmega328.hex). Simply replace the hex file in AVR boards package with this one.

Comment: I can add more details or even build and test the bootloader and provide boards.txt settings since I have this on my TODO list.

Comment: Thanks @Juraj, that would be helpful! I am currently diving in the source code/makefile to see what are the option I need to enable to build the bootloader and you were right about the do_spm not being enabled by default.

Comment: @FallaCoulibaly, I discovered that do_spm is in the normal build of Optiboot8. BIGBOOT is not required. I modified the answer.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick

Comment: but if somebody ever needs the big version of Optiboot including my `copy_flash_pages` function, here it is https://github.com/jandrassy/my_boards. about `copy_flash_pages`: https://github.com/Optiboot/optiboot/pull/269